# why inserting a null value to not null column do not terminate sql script but conversion failure do

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @tempdb AS TABLE (col INT NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @tempdb ( col )VALUES  (1)

--part1:
--Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'col', table '@tempdb'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
INSERT INTO @tempdb ( col )VALUES  (NULL)
--the whole script didn't abort

SELECT * FROM  @tempdb -- this line is executed

--part2:
--Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'asdsd' to data type int.
INSERT INTO @tempdb ( col )VALUES  ('asdsd')
--script terminated here

SELECT * FROM  @tempdb --didn't execute
```

the two cases above both got error, but why case 2 terminated sql script and case 1 didn't?

Comment: Sql server do not terminate when any error thrown, there has second statement is always execute.

Comment: but the last `SELECT * FROM  @tempdb --didn't execute` didn't execute

Comment: it is depends on sql server error.

Comment: Unless one of the T-SQL language designers happens to be around, nobody is going to be able to answer *why*. All I can say is that T-SQL is a very crufty language that has a lot of misfeatures, and if this is the worst one you've encountered so far, you're quite lucky.

Comment: SQL Server has Error Severity Levels 0-25, If severity is >= 19 the current batch process will be terminated. For more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx